# clickatell sms messages fail with no error or notification for non-US numbers

Tags: clickatell

I have a web application that sends verification codes to users through clickatell. Nearly all users are in the US, and those work fine, but I have about 5 with international phone numbers who receive no texts.

I have a page set up to accept delivery notifications and dump them into a log file.

If I send a message to a US number, like +18161234567 I get a notification like so:

> integrationName=MyIntegration&messageId=*******************&clientMessageId=&to=18161234567&from=1##########&status=DELIVERED_TO_GATEWAY&statusDesc=DELIVERED_TO_GATEWAY&timestamp=1502911816000

But if I send a message to a non-US number, like +393921234567, I get no response from the clickatell server at all. It's like they don't even get the request. The phone number is the only difference between the two requests.

I have a case open with clickatell support but they have been less than insightful so far, just telling me they need a messageID or error code to investigate further, but since I get no response, I have none to give them.

Has anyone else experienced this or have any ideas I can use to troubleshoot?

We have a two-way number because that is required for sending texts in the US. However, clickatell notes on the two-way settings page that

> If the country does not support two-way messaging, Clickatell will not submit the message (you will not be charged for messages that aren't successfully submitted)

I can't seem to find a list of countries that do or do not support two-way messaging. Do I need to add a separate integration without two-way  messaging to support my international numbers?

UPDATE: Upon further research, my international users are in 3 countries. Italy, which does not support two-way messaging, and France and Mexico, both of which do support it. Yet none of the three are working.

FURTHER UPDATE: I have tried creating a separate integration just for Italy, since they do not support two-way messaging. I have set it up to use the clickatell automatic mobile number formatting for that country. The result is the same. No text is sent and I receive no response of any kind from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check/provide response from server when you submit message with number: +393921234567.

Most likely you get validation error - that this destination number not covered by number that you bought.

Have a nice day.

Comment: I do not receive any response from the server. As clearly stated.

Comment: yes you are right, sorry. Did you try both types of integration: HTTP and REST ?